# Prove $M$ is a Maximal Ideal in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

A problem from introduction to abstract algebra by Hungerford.

It asks:
*If $p$ is a prime integer, prove that $M$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$*, where $M =\{(pa,b)\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$

Though, we know that an ideal is maximal iff $\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{M}$ is a field. Isn't $\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{M} = (\mathbb Z_{p}, \mathbb Z_{b})$? And since $b$ can be any integer, say $6$, then this is not a field.  And so $M$ must not be maximal?

Can someone please show what I am misunderstanding?  Thanks.

Comment: $b$ is not fixed - it is a general integer. The ideal has the form $p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Don't forget to prove it is an ideal.

Comment: $M$ is the kernel of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+p\mathbb Z$

Comment: Right, thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing well, but this isn't right: $\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{M} = (\mathbb Z_{p}, \mathbb Z_{b})$

It's true that everything in the left side of the pairs is of the form $pa$ for $a$ ranging over $\Bbb Z$, and those are exactly the elements of $(p)\lhd \Bbb Z$, so the left part is indeed $\Bbb Z_p$. But in the right hand side, $b$ can be anything, including $1$!

So $\Bbb Z_b$ is not right but $\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{M} = (\mathbb Z_{p}, ?)$ (you suddenly realize what it actually should be in the comments below...)

Comment: Oh. I see.  Thanks.  So, just to make sure $\frac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{M} = (\mathbb Z_{P}, 0) \cong \mathbb Z_{P}$ which is a field, hence $M$ must be maximal?

Comment: @DavidJhoo Right!

Answer (score 2):

Add an ordered pair $(c,d)$, where $c$ is not a multiple of $p$. Using the [Bézout Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we find that $(1,k)$ is in the resulting ideal for some $k$.  But $(0,k)$ is in the ideal, so $(1,0)$ is.  Since $(0,1)$ is in the ideal, we get all of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Great, thanks.  So we are letting $I = (c,d)$ be some other ideal s.t $M \subset I$.  Then $\exists i \in I: i \nmid p$.  So then by Bezout's identity $(1,k) \in I$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. Then we see that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are in the ideal, hence $(1,1) \in I$ and $I = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $M$ must be maximal.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The answer was intended to confront the problem in a concrete "hands on" way.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.  This proof follows more closely to the chapter proofs in the readings.

Comment: I read your comment too quickly. In your notation, we suppose that $I$ is an ideal which is a proper extension of $M$, and we let $i=(c,d)$ be in $I$ but not in $M$. Then continue as you wrote. (I am objecting to the $I=(c,d)$.)

Comment: Ok I see the mistake.  Looks like if I try to define $I = \{...\}$ s.t its a proper extension of $M$, the only choice is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$... just like we proved.  I guess I should have seen it that way faster since $\mathbb Z_{P}$ is always maximal.

Comment: I mean $(p)$ is always maximal.